# What to call value compared with the previous day's value in stock exchange?

Tags: terminology, vocabulary, business-language

[image: Stock ticker indicating change in price]

I'd like to know what to call the value compared with the previous day's value in English.

This image is what I screen-captured in tradingview.com

Q1. what do you call these values in English? -> (0.37%, 0.78%, 0.25%)

Q2. what do you call these values in English? -> (9.3, 46.2, 0.00297)

Comment: https://economics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: I think they’re literally called the *daily change*.

Comment: Informally, "Nasdaq up 78 [basis] points", and the concept in general (i.e. not only when applied to indexes/stocks) is often read (informally) as "day on day [percentage] change", where the parts in square brackets are not usually verbalised, e.g. "day on day change of up half a percent".

Answer (score 6):

It is called [daily percentage change](https://www.earnforex.com/metatrader-indicators/Daily-Percentage-Change/) :

The example below refers to currencies but the same apply to stocks:

> - the change of currency rate related to the previous daily close and displayed in percentage points.

[Percentage Change](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/p/percentage-change.asp):

> - Percentage change is a simple mathematical concept that represents the degree of change over time. It is used for many purposes in finance, ***often to represent the price change of a security.***

BREAKING DOWN 'Percentage Change':

> - Percentage change can be applied to any quantity that you measure over time. Let's say you are tracking the quoted price of a security. If the price increased, use the formula [(New Price - Old Price)/Old Price] and then multiply that number by 100.  If the price decreased, use the formula [(Old Price - New Price)/Old Price] and multiply that number by 100.

(Investopedia)

Answer (score 3):

Those are daily percentage changes, which is a common way to report relative change. The other numbers are the actual daily change.

For more details, see the [Wikipedia article on "relative change”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_change_and_difference?wprov=sfti1https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_change_and_difference?wprov=sfti1).

The linked article is long, but the basic idea is stated as

"In any quantitative science, the ... [term] relative change ... [is] used to compare two quantities while taking into account the "sizes" of the things being compared. The comparison is expressed as a ratio and is a unitless number. By multiplying these ratios by 100 they can be expressed as percentages so the terms percentage change, percent(age) difference, or relative percentage difference are also commonly used." In my personal experience, "percentage change" is by far the most common.

Comment: Please support all answers you post with evidence. Otherwise they’re indistinguishable from opinions. I’m going to downvote this for now, and then reverse my downvote (and potentially upvote) after you [edit] in authoritative support for your answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Bron I have added a citation to Wikipedia on relative change as a common, generic type of computation in all the quantitative sciences. In the meantime, another answer has been given referring to specific use in finance. Thank you for the recommendation to add an authority. In this case, the terms are so common within the field that the need for an authority had not occurred to me on my own.

Comment: Thanks for the good faith and cooperation. I’ve undone my downvote and added an upvote, so now you’re par with the other posted answer. I’ve also added a link to the WP article you referenced. I think it would improve your answer enormously to quote the portions of that article which support your answer.

Comment: @ Bron Thanks again. I am fairly new to the site and appreciate pointers on how to do better. I have been commenting for a long while at various math sites, where there are different conventions about behavior: there demonstration is strongly preferred to authority.